# Trigger a Jenkins build from TestRail

Tags: testing, build, triggers, jenkins

I am trying to trigger a [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) build from [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/), a test case management software.  To my knowledge, these two software don't formally support each other. But TestRail does have a JS/CSS editor that allows the user to customize their UI. I was hoping to be able to implement a button that would be able to trigger the build in Jenkins. But it turns out, the editor cannot interpret HTML.

If anyone already went through this process, can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Hey, check out this post as well: http://bruteforce.gr/automated-testing-integrating-testrail-local-qa-environment.html

Answer (score 6):

one of the TestRail developers here. You can trigger automated tests from within TestRail and you would use the following approach:

- Add a button to TestRail's user interface using UI Scripts. You can use JavaScript/jQuery to inject any custom buttons/HTML code as needed: http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-integration/custom-uiscripts
- Your custom button would point to a custom server-side script that you need to write. The server-side script would actually trigger your Jenkins build (as this wouldn't be possible from JavaScript)
- Your automated tests would use TestRail's API to submit the test results back to TestRail: http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api/start

Please note that most teams simply execute/trigger their automated tests outside of TestRail instead, e.g. together with a daily build or similar.

Update: we also have a full code example on how to trigger automated tests from TestRail on our website here now:

http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-custom/automation-trigger

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I got the button working successfully.  Struggling to get automated test results into TestRail now but I guess that's a different discussion.
- Raj

Comment: I am still struggling here. help me pls